# Can't connect to SQL Server with node.js?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, npm, electron

Today I was trying to build my first app with electron and for this I need to connect to a SQL Server instance.

I got `mssql` (from npm) and wrote this block of code:

```
var sql = require("mssql");

var dbConfig = {
            server: "SERVER7\\SLATCAT",
            database: "Slatcat",
            user: "slatcat",
            password: "Sl@tc@t2017",
            port: "65400"
};

function connect() {
     var conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(dbConfig);
     var req = new sql.Request(conn);

    conn.connect(function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        else {
            req.query("select * FROM tags_table",function(err, recordset) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    console.log(recordset);
                }

                conn.close();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

It throws this error:

> ConnectionError: Accesso non riuscito per l'utente 'slatcat'.
>
> at Connection.tedious.once.err (C:\users\madalin.necula\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:216:17)
>   at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:293:19)
>   at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>   at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
>   at Connection.processLogin7Response (C:\users\madalin.necula\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1091:16)
>       at Connection.message (C:\users\madalin.necula\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1573:21)
>       at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\users\madalin.necula\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:857:45)
>       at MessageIO. (C:\users\madalin.necula\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:751:18)
>       at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
>       at MessageIO.emit (events.js:188:7)

I've tried to change the account psw but i can't figure out what's denying the connection. Is there anyone who can help me understand?!

Thanks in advance

---

Comment: EDIT: No matter which user i pick, it still return the same error and i'm pretty sure the psw and the user id are correct because i can log in from the management studio

Comment: Go to SQL Server error log, find there 18654 error, the next row explain the reason of failure

Comment: Lol it says: 

`2017-11-16 09:29:24.13 Logon       Login failed for user 'slatcat'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: <local machine>]`

But the password is the one i've always been using for that database. I mean...it's the same psw i use to connect from the management studio

Comment: Server cannot invent, it's just a program. It receives your password and compare its hash to what is in its system table. You supply wrong password, I don't know if it's your program to pass it incorrectly or it's you to write it wrong...

Comment: Can you print your connection string from your program to see if it's correct? If it's equal to what is in your code?

Comment: It was my bad...i was watching to the wrong log (i've got multiple istances)..the right log says that the server is not configured to achieve sql authentication, but in the server property the remote connection is allowed.

here you are : `var dbConfig = {
            server: "SERVER7\\SLATCAT",
            database: "Slatcat",
            user: "slatcat",
            password: "Sl@tc@t2017",
            port: "65400"
       };`

Comment: Finally i made it.
The problem was related to a strange thing it's appening that i can't understand yet...in my config var i set the server to : SERVER7\\SLATCAT which is my server and the istance i would like to reach but instead of connecting to the SLATCAT istance it connects to the SQLexpress istance..... the strange thing is that: the port i actually gave to the js script is the port of the other istance (SLATCAT)

Comment: You should never pass both port and instance name in your connection string: when the port is passed, instance name is just IGNORED. So you can use even SERVER7\\bla-bla-bla, but if the port is specified, you'll be connected to the instance that listens on that port

Comment: When instead you pass only instance name, SQL Browser should run. It accepts instance name and gives its port as the answer

Comment: Fixed it, it runs perfectly, thank you so much :)